# How can if() evaluate incorrectly in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have a simple bit of logic.

```
int i = 0;
if (i < 0) { 
  //whatever; 
}
```

When I debug with VS I see `i` set to 0 BUT the if evaluates as false! How can this be?

GUYS. Perhaps I could have worded it better!!!  The above expression SHOULD evaluate as false when i is 0 which I see when I hover over it in VS BUT it goes into the brackets and does "whatever"... WHICH is not right.

**EDIT:** Please see my [similarly named but more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401497/c-visual-studio-appears-to-follow-an-incorrect-code-path/6408807#6408807) for a solution.

Comment: 0 is not less than 0

Comment: Simple Logic isn't simple enough.

Comment: This question is going to smash the record for most semantically-identical answers posted.

Comment: I think downvoting is harsh however. The question is well-asked, and the OP has attempted to figure it out with his debugger. He just didn't understand the root cause of the bug, and that's OK.

Comment: Re the Edit: The code posted will _not_ execute `whatever`. So there is another misconception/misread.

Comment: @raz - Well asked? Are you serious? He utterly failed to explain what the actual problem was

Comment: @bemace It was a silly question, but perfectly clear in what it was asking.

Comment: @bemace Ah, sorry. I've just seen the edit which has changed the question completely since my comment above. Now it's worthy of a downvote.

Comment: bernace - why is it a silly question? I have a bug. I have given a simple bit of code to explain the issue. I have NEVER seen VS do something like this before. I think you might be being flippant instead of helpong me.

Comment: Henk, you are correct in that "whatever" should not execute. HOWEVER - it does! This is my issue! Obviously something much more subtle is going wrong and I came to this site to get some serious help.

Comment: @ManInMoon: Have you tried all of the usual stuff, performing clean builds etc?

Comment: Yes, and complete reboot. It's very odd. Now I have put a load of log lines in and am stepping through the code - some of the loglines(Console.Writelines) are missed out!

Comment: If you want to have this re-opened, perhaps edit your question?

Answer (score 9):

0 is not less than 0. Its equal to. Do `if (i <= 0)`

Answer (score 5):

That's because 0 < 0 is false.

Answer (score 2):

If `i` equals 0, then it is false, because it is not less than 0.

What you are thinking of is `if(i == 0)` or `if (i <= 0)` (or for that matter `if(i >= 0)`).  Each of these are true if `i` equals `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Because i is not less than zero.  So, the expression evaluates as false, which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

0 is NOT less than 0. it is less than OR EQUAL to 0

Comment: Exactly. Therefore it should NOT do "Whatever" right? But mine does...

Comment: @ManInMoon: So why did you say "it evaluates as false"?

Comment: Sorry Jon my wording was unclear - I have edited it now

Answer (score 2):

It evaluates to false because 0 is not less than 0.

Answer (score 2):

`0 < 0` will always be `false`. Under what condition do you expect it to evaluate to `true`?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is because i isn't less than 0.

In order for the if statement to evaluate to true, i would need to be a negative integer.

Comment: Paste your actual code segment. Without more information most people will just assume the PEBCAK

Answer (score 1):

`0 < 0` is false.  use `<=` if you want it to evaluate to true if `i` is `0`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your simple bit of logic needs to be:

```
int i = 0;
if(i <= 0) {Whatever }
```