# c# Visual Studio appears to follow an incorrect code path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, path

Below is a small snippet taken from a fairly large app to simplify my question. I submitted this question before, but my poor wording caused it to be closed before I managed to edit my question.

This is the current snippet to which I have added some logging lines.

```
int i = 0; 
Console.WriteLine("Before brackets");
if (i < 0) 
{ 
      Console.WriteLine("Inside brackets");
      return MyArray[i]; 
}
```

When I debug with VS I see:

```
i set to 0
if evaluates as false (when I hover over it in VS) 
In Output: Before brackets
```

Then the debugger steps **inside** the brackets and the `return MyArray[i]` is executed however I do not see `Inside brackets` in the output by the time I have stepped through to the `return MyArray[i]` line.

This behaviour is obviously (to me) wrong and I wondered if anyone else had encountered something like this.

I am on a Windows XP, 64bit machine , with VS10 and .Net4.0.

Moon

**ADDITIONAL1**

I have been asked by Henk to provide a "console App" which I have done below. HOWEVER, as I would suspect, it does NOT SHOW the issue. I believe there is something else (threads?) causing me an in issue in my real app - and I obviously can post that. I realise I am not giving you a clearly defined problem - if I could, I would. That is why I am asking this question - incase it strikes a cord with somebody having something similar. For good order, here is console version which DOES NOT exhibit the problem. I have a feeling putting it on here will add to the confusion...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Mods = new string[] { "Cat", "Dog", "Geek" };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string t = "Geek";
            Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + FindD(t));

        }

        public static string FindD(string ModelFullName)
        {
            int ix = Array.IndexOf<string>(Mods, ModelFullName);

            Console.WriteLine("ix: " + ix + " = " + (ix < 0).ToString());
            if (ix < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2ix: " + ix + " = " + (ix < 0).ToString());
                Error.Process(ErrorLevel.Critical, "ModelName not found: " + ModelFullName);
            }
            try
            {

                return Mods[ix];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Error.Process(ErrorLevel.Critical, "Could not point to Mod for: " + ModelFullName);
            }

            return null;
        }

        enum ErrorLevel { Note, Critical };
        class Error
        {
            public static void Process(ErrorLevel EL, string message)
            {
                if (EL == ErrorLevel.Critical)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Critical error: " + GetStackTrace() + message);
                }
            }

            public static string GetStackTrace()
            {
                StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();           // get call stack
                StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();  // get method calls (frames)

                string st = "";
                // write call stack method names
                for (int i = 6; i > 1; i--)
                {
                    StackFrame stackFrame = stackFrames[i];
                    st = st + stackFrame.GetMethod().Name + "/";
                }

                return st;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ADDITIONAL 2**

It seems that my issue is NOT one of the execution path going a wrong route ONLY VS debugger. i.e. It appears as if I am going inside the brackets, because debugger steps on the last statement, but the results I actually get appear correct.

Comment: @ManInMoon - `i < 0` will evaluate to false when `i == 0`?

Comment: I'm unsure what the question is. 0 is not less than 0, so the `if` statement evaluates false, and the code inside it is not evaluated. Hence, you don't see "Inside Brackets" in the output, which is correct. I see no problem here. Obviously the code would break if the condition does evaluate true because negative array indices are not valid.

Comment: Are you saying it is actually executing `return MyArray[i]` but not writing the output or are you saying it's not going into the if condition?

Comment: Btw: I don't think it's legal to create an array with a negative length.

Comment: Yes I agree. BUT that is really the crux. It does execute some statements inside the brackets - and not others. So in this case it does not print "Inside Brackets". BUT it does to to the Returm line.

Comment: ChrisWue: Yes it does execute return MyArray[i] - which I agree it shouldn't. Yes about the neg length - I simplified what I put on the post - obviously here that could happen. In the real app it does not.

Comment: Are you sure you have built the project in Debug mode? In release mode optimizations can happen and sometimes the debugger gets confused.

Comment: ChrisWue. I have unintentionally misled you slightly. return MyArray[i] looks like it is being executed because VS steps onto it i.e. it goes inside the brackets - THEN it appears to ignore it. I have not seen that before. Are there times when debug appears to go down one path whilst the actually code doesn't?
evilone: You can't accept a "comment" can you? Or are you refering to previous questions?

Comment: Still the same incomplete and nonsensical question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/6389261/60761

Comment: @manin If you want to make this a serious question, reproduce this in a _complete_ piece of code. Like a Console app of < 50 lines.

Comment: Henk: I am doing my best to work in SO style having taken onboard the various reprimands. Please see edit of question above

Comment: @main: you're getting cloer, it's no longer "the if() statement doesn't work". Now you'll have to make the test program more like the real thing, step by step.

Comment: Henk, the real app is huge - I need to find another to solve this bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue after a tip I found from a google web search. It seems I was running the debugger in `"Optmise Code"` mode. This is something I checked early on, BUT what I didn't spot wad that although I had this option deselected for Debug Mode - I had "Release" selected in the Standard Toolbar. When I switched to "`Debug`" the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing something, but this is quite logic ?

- i is set to zero.

  - i is not less than
    zero.
  - Inside brackets is NOT
    outputted.

This is logical, isn't it ?
Step through the code using the debugger.  You'll see it makes sense.

Comment: I do Frederik, but the return MyArray[i] line DOES get executed

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your if statement isn't as follows:

```
if (i < 0)
    Console.WriteLine(...);
    return MyArray(i);
```

Note the misleading indentation and the lack of brackets.

Comment: Inbetween: Good call, but no it isn't that

Answer (score 0):

If `i = 0` then `i < 0` is false. If you set your condition to `i <= 0`, then it executes the condition.

Comment: I don't it to execute. I am confused becuase it does execute the second line reutrn MyArray[i]